# STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION when middle clicking page. Ajax + PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Anytime I middle-click the div ajax loads a php into when the php is loaded, the site crashes with "STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION"

My AJAX script:

```
<script>
function loadBlog() {
  // Show the loader
  document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "block";

  // Make an AJAX request to fetch the blog content
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      // Hide the loader
      document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";

      // Update the blog container with the fetched content
      document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhr.open("GET", "blog.php", true);
  xhr.send();
}
</script>
```

And heres my PHP it calls upon:

```
<?php
//$Parsedown->setSafeMode(true); // Get all post UUIDs and sort by creation date of post.md file (most recent first)
$dir = "./data/posts"; // replace with the name of your subdirectory
$dirs = array_filter(glob($dir . '/*'), 'is_dir'); // get all directories in subdirectory
//sort based on date set in post.json
usort($dirs, function($a, $b) {
  $json_a = $a . '/post.json'; // get path to post.json file
  $json_b = $b . '/post.json'; // get path to post.json file
  if (file_exists($json_a) && file_exists($json_b)) { // check if post.json file exists
    $contents_a = file_get_contents($json_a); // get contents of post.json file
    $contents_b = file_get_contents($json_b); // get contents of post.json file
    $data_a = json_decode($contents_a, true); // decode contents of post.json file into an array
    $data_b = json_decode($contents_b, true); // decode contents of post.json file into an array
    return strtotime($data_b['date']) - strtotime($data_a['date']); // sort by date
  }
});
// loop through all directories
foreach ($dirs as $dir) {
  $json = $dir . '/post.json'; // get path to post.json file
  if (file_exists($json)) { // check if post.json file exists
    $contents = file_get_contents($json); // get contents of post.json file
    $data = json_decode($contents, true); // decode contents of post.json file into an array
    $uuid = $data['uuid']; // get UUID of post
    $title = $data['title']; // get title of post
    $date = $data['date']; // get date of post
    $author = $data['author']; // get author of post
    $description = $data['description']; // get description of post
    $tags = $data['tags']; // get tags of post
    $image = $data['image']; // get image of post
    $post = $dir . '/post.md'; // get path to post.md file
    if (file_exists($post)) { // check if post.md file exists
      $contents = file_get_contents($post); // get contents of post.md file
      $html = $contents; // use the raw contents of the post.md file
      echo '<div class="post">';
      echo '<h1 class="post-title"><a href="/post.php?uuid=' . $uuid . '">' . $title . '</a></h1>';
      echo '<p class="post-date">' . $date . '</p>';
      echo '<p class="post-author">' . $author . '</p>';
      echo '<p class="post-description">' . $description . '</p>';
      echo '<p class="post-tags">' . $tags . '</p>';
      echo '<img class="post-image" src="' . $image . '">';
      echo '<div class="post-content">' . $html . '</div>';
      echo '</div>';
    }
  }
}
 ?>
```

This only started happening recently. Other renditions of the bigger php have been used elsewhere in dev and live environments with 0 issue. Perhaps its an issue with Apache itself?

Comment: does this only happen in specific browsers?

Comment: Can you clarify what "*site crashes*" means?  Where do you see STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION, on the page, or on the console?  Check your browser's devtoos network tab - does the AJAX request happen, and do you get a response?  Do you see your loading animation come on/off?  Can you give a sample of what the full rendered HTML response is, eg what `$html` looks like?

Comment: try changing browsers

Comment: I found in the internet that you have to restart your browser or maybe that's in your environment

Comment: Do you get the error only on chrome ? If so, update your chrome. Otherwise check your static resources like Css, Images, Js, do not load them more that one time. And for the last suggestion please check the PHP output using other tools like Postman or other libraries like jQuery. I think the problem has nothing to do with your PHP script and is a frontend issue (browser or js)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the cause.  Why would one website show `STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION` and not others?  I discovered the theme we were using in WordPress was loading font-awesome font twice.  Apparent the Chrome doesn't know how to overwrite the font. This was an intermittent error so it was difficult to troubleshoot.  I discovered the problem by looking in the Network Tab of Developer Tools in Chrome.  I found that the last file to load was always the font-awesome font, and the browser would crash at that point.